# smooth surface plot with pgfplots/gnuplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

i want to create a smooth surface plot with pgf-plots and gnuplot. The following code yields a graph, but i need much more gridpoints along y-direction. How can i reach this?

The increase of samples doesn´t work here. The result then become worse...

Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=0.9\textwidth,
        3d box,
        view={20}{25},
        plot box ratio=3 10 5,  
        ylabel={y},
        xlabel={x},     
        ]
\addplot3[raw gnuplot,   
        surf,
        %empty line = jump,
        samples=100,
        ] 
gnuplot[surf,
    mesh/check=false,
    ]{
    n=1e-5;
    b=100;
    h=10;
    p=-0.0001;
    K=((16*b**2)/(n*pi**3))*(-p);
Sum(i,x,y)=K*(((-1)**(0.5*((2*i-1)-1)))*(1-((cosh(((2*i-1)*pi*x)/(2*b)))/(cosh(((2*i-1)*pi*h)/(2*b)))))*((cos(((2*i-1)*pi*y)/(2*b)))/((2*i-1)**3)));
    u(i,x,y)=(i==0)?0:(u(i-1,x,y)+Sum(i,x,y));
    splot [-h:h] [-b:b] u(25,x,y)/u(25,0,0);
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that pgfplots did not properly respect the 'raw gnuplot' option in one place: it used its own keys `samples` and `samples y` to determine the input matrix size, but it does not communicate them to gnuplot.

The developer version of pgfplots now contains a bugfix for this behavior.
Until this version becomes stable, I can offer you a (very simple) work-around (see below).

However, you still need to communicate the sample counts to gnuplot (in case of `raw gnuplot`, pgfplots assumes that you take full responsability).

Both these things can be acomplished using

```
\addplot3[raw gnuplot,   
        surf,
        %empty line = jump,
                samples=25,    %---
        samples y=50,  %---
        ] 
gnuplot[surf,
    %mesh/check=false,
    ]{
    n=1e-5;
    b=100;
    h=10;
    p=-0.0001;
    set samples 25,50;    %---
    set isosamples 25,50; %---
    K=((16*b**2)/(n*pi**3))*(-p);
Sum(i,x,y)=K*(((-1)**(0.5*((2*i-1)-1)))*(1-((cosh(((2*i-1)*pi*x)/(2*b)))/(cosh(((2*i-1)*pi*h)/(2*b)))))*((cos(((2*i-1)*pi*y)/(2*b)))/((2*i-1)**3)));
    u(i,x,y)=(i==0)?0:(u(i-1,x,y)+Sum(i,x,y));
    splot [-h:h] [-b:b] u(25,x,y)/u(25,0,0);
    };
```

the (pgfplots) key `samples=<x>` must match the first argument of `set isosamples=<x>, <y>`  and the (pgfplots) key `samples y=<y>` must match the second argument. I honestly do not know how to combine the gnuplot options `set samples` and `set isosamples` - I suppose `set samples` is unnecessary here. This should (generally) solve this bug.

I strongly recommend to uncomment `mesh/check=false` (it indicates that pgfplots could not read the matrix structure).

Comment: I'm glad I could help - and that I could eliminate one further bug :)  . You can mark the post as "answered" to close the thread.